# Cant read value from datagridview cell before cellendedit

Tags: c#, datagridview

Heay guys,
I have this code. even though I don't think there is a problem in it

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cell.Value.ToString());
     }
}
```

But for some stupid reason, it doesn´t show the value of the cell that I haven´t ended editing. Is there any property that would allow me to do that?

I have a form with `Datagridview`. I write "aaa" into first cell and of the first row, write "bbb" into the second cell and then close the form. `OnClose event` performs code from above and the output is "aaa". The thing is that it does not happen if, before I close the form I click into, for example, the first cell in the second row(that means I trigger EndCellEdit event on the second cell in the first row).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does it show? Can you be more clear about the problem?

Comment: There you go man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `DataGridView` when changing the value of a cell, the `CellValueChangedEvent` is only fired when leaving the cell (for example, if you click on another cell in your case). The event is not fired when you change the value and then just close the form. For a workaround in your form closing event you can remove your focus from the `DataGridView` which will cause `CellValueChangedEvent` to fire. You can set focus to a label or any other control of your form.

Comment: Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus(v=vs.110).aspx) if you dont know how to change focus

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for.